# 3/4 Black Poly Main Line Replaced With 3/4 Pex

Tags: water, pex

Due to many leaks in the existing main supply line, plumbers have replaced my 3/4 black poly line from the meter in to my house with 3/4 pex. Existing line was about 25 years old.

The new 3/4 pex line had to be routed a different route in my yard, and the over all length of the run went from 60 ft to about 120ft .

I think 3/4 pex is smaller in diameter than the previous water line pipe. Water flow inside the house seems ok, as long as only one faucet is running.

Should the plumbers have used 1” pex?

Comment: The two lines should have similar inside diameters, maybe slight difference, but not enough to affect flow or pressure.  If pressure/flow is reduced I would suspect a blockage in the line.

Comment: If it's PEX-B you might be experiencing a constraint around the fitting. Poly pipe and PEX-A both expand around the fitting, so the interior of the fitting is nominally 3/4 and real-world 0.68 inches or so. PEX-B has the same inside diameter but since unlike the other two it doesn't expand, the fittings for it are smaller, usually around 0.54 inches. That's a significant difference and can be a pinch point. How did they connect it to the rest of your plumbing?

Comment: I'd have gone up to 1" PEX at a minimum, but that's because I'd rather not see a house locked out of an otherwise relatively inexpensive fire safety upgrade because of a chintzy water service replacement...